# Combine onChange and onAppear events in SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I'm observe a property on a view using the `onChange` modifier. However, I'd also like the same piece of code to run on the initial value as well because sometimes the data is injected in the initializer or asynchronously loaded later.

For example, I have a view that gets a model injected. Sometimes this model has data in it to begin with (like previews), or is asynchronously retrieved from the network.

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Counter: \(model.counter)")
            Button("Increment") { model.counter += 1 }
        }
        .onChange(of: model.counter, perform: someLogic)
        .onAppear { someLogic(counter: model.counter) }
    }
    
    private func someLogic(counter: Int) {
        print("onAppear: \(counter)")
    }
}
```

In both `onAppear` and `onChange` cases, I'd like to run `someLogic(counter:)`. Is there a better way to get this behaviour or combine them?

Comment: Not sure I fully understood your use case, but I think you could just use `.onReceive(model.$counter, perform: someLogic)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like `onReceive` may be what you need. Instead of:

```
.onChange(of: model.counter, perform: someLogic)
.onAppear { someLogic(counter: model.counter) }
```

you could do:

```
.onReceive(model.$counter, perform: someLogic)
```

The difference between `onChange` and `onReceive` is that the latter also fires when the view is initialised.

---

**onChange**

If you take a closer look at `onChange`, you'll see that it performs an action only when a value *changes* (and this doesn't happen when a view is initialised).

```
/// Adds a modifier for this view that fires an action when a specific
/// value changes.
/// ...
@inlinable public func onChange<V>(of value: V, perform action: @escaping (V) -> Void) -> some View where V : Equatable
```

---

**onReceive**

However, the counter's publisher will emit the value also when a view is initialised. This will make `onReceive` perform an action passed as a parameter.

```
/// Adds an action to perform when this view detects data emitted by the
/// given publisher.
/// ...
@inlinable public func onReceive<P>(_ publisher: P, perform action: @escaping (P.Output) -> Void) -> some View where P : Publisher, P.Failure == Never
```

---

Just note that `onReceive` is **not** an *equivalent* of `onChange`+`onAppear`.

`onAppear` is called when a view *appears* but in some cases a view may be initialised again without firing `onAppear`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. And behaviour is better than onAppear!

Answer (score 4):

Apple understood this requirement so they gave us [`task(id:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)) which will run the operation both when the UI described by the `View` data struct appears on screen of if the `id:` value changes (it must be an `Equatable`). It has the added benefits that the operation is cancelled if the value is changed so the next operation doesn't overlap with the first; it also is cancelled if the UI disappears. `.task` removes the need for `@StateObject` so just make an async func that returns a result and save it in a `@State`.

**Example**

```
...
let number: Int
...
.task(id: number){
    print("task") // called both on appear and when changed. If an await method is called, it is cancelled if the number changes or if the View disappears.
    someState = await fetchSomething(number)
}
.onAppear {
    print("onAppear") // only called during appear.
}
.onChange(of: number) { number in 
    print("onChange") // only called when number is changed.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell you a real accident.

In a navigation stack, push A -> push B. Now B is the on the screen

`onReceive` can be received on A too even it's not on the screen, while `onChange` only can be triggered on B. In this case, `onReceive` is very dangerous.

For example, if you have a global state and try to push to another view once `onReceived` or `onChange` is triggered on both A and B, then you will see the view is pushed twice since both A and B triggers.

Comment: You need to add a parameter to mark A/B.

Comment: I too agree with you.