# In swift how can i get size of Image() in pixel units

Tags: swiftui, qr-code

[New to swift]
I am currently displaying a qr code as outlined in https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-create-a-qr-code.
I am setting the size using `.resizable().frame(width:500,height:500)`
This is being run on swift playgrounds on ipad 10.

- The size ( ex: 500 ) doesnt appear to be the size in pixels of the Image. What is the size number indicate ?
- My goal is to know the size of the qr code in pixel units that was displayed on the screen.
- Trying GeometryReader() out at the moment, does it return size in pixel units ?

currently trying out https://stackoverflow.com/a/66399037/3654791 , but am running into `Cannot find "Just" in scope` error

Comment: You should show some code. You likely want `scaledToFit` before the frame. The frame is in points (not pixels). Pixels will depend on the density of the screen.