# Is there a better way to use repeated Spacers in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to display a View in the top 1/3 of the screen. In order to do so, I manipulate it as so:

```swift
var body: some View {
 VStack{
  Spacer()
  Text("I like chipotle")
  Spacer()
  Spacer()
 }
}
```

While that works for smaller examples, I wonder if there is a more declarative way to do this so if I for example want to put a view in the top 1/6 of a screen? I think about flex box where you can set the flex value of specific children to make them take up different percentages.

Comment: SwiftUI.Layout was made for this type of work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let partOfScreen: CGFloat = 1/3

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("I like chipotle")
                    .padding(.top, geo.size.height * partOfScreen)
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add `.ignoresSafeArea(.all)` on `GeometryReader` if the entire screen area is needed

Comment: No need for the `Spacer()` or even the `VStack`. Also adding padding does not arrange it in the exact center of the 1/3 of the top area. You may want to use frame instead

Comment: Yes, my mistake, GeometryReader puts the inner content to the top, Spacer is not really needed

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I didn’t really understand how frame would help here, can you explain? To really center the content, I would determine size of Text view something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452647/how-we-can-get-and-read-size-of-a-text-with-geometryreader-in-swiftui and subtract half of it in the padding

Comment: Subtraction will work, but why don't you use the `.center` aligned frame (which is the default alignment)? the a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76490184/5623035)

Comment: Why is it necessary to make frame of Text view so big? By placing it between other views or a view below it we probably won't get the result that we expect

Comment: As the OP says: `I want to display a View in the top 1/3 of the screen`. If the need is different like you say, you can make a container around them and frame that instead.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any `Spacer` You can directly assign the size to a view relative to its parent using the `GeometryReader`:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    Text("I like Chipotle")
        .frame(height: proxy.size.height/3.rounded())
    }
}
```

#### Quick Tip

> Always try to `round` position and size values. Otherwise, it will heavily impact the render engine to render fractional pixels and you may experience lags and drop frames.