# Triggering an event when all child views have been measured (GeometryReader, ViewPreferences)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a parent view, consisting of several child views of the same Class, but of different sizes (they grow or shrink according the size of some content in them). Let's call the parent view Board, and the child views Shapes.

I would like to auto-arrange the Shapes so that they fill the available space optimally. I have already chosen an algorithm for doing so.

However, in order to execute this algorithm, I would need a data structure consisting of the widths and heights of each Shape once the Shapes have all been rendered.

I have found out about ViewPreferences for propagating the size information up the view stack. So let's say I take SizeModifier and SizePreferenceKey from here (https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/15/the-magic-of-view-preferences-in-swiftui/).

```
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct SizeModifier: ViewModifier {
    private var sizeView: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size)
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.background(sizeView)
    }
}
```

Essentially this is a ViewModifier that puts a transparent background to the view it is applied to, wrapped in a GeometryReader, so that the size of the View it is applied to, can be measured.

If I apply this SizeModifier to the Shape views, I can receive their sizes in onPreferenceChange:

```
Shape(//shape args//)
    .modifier(SizeModifier())
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
      // Do something with the size
    }
```

What is missing is a way to have an event that fires when the size of all such Shape objects in a parent view have been determined (that is, when all onPreferenceChange events have fired at least once). What would be a right way to catch such an event? If I could  re-map the callback based API of onPreferenceChange to a Promise, I could build a TaskGroup of all such Promises and listen for its completion.

I have found out about Continuations and tried to do something along the lines of:

```
let size = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
  Shape(//shape args//)
    .modifier(SizeModifier())
    .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
      continuation.resume(returning: size)
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get "SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: //parent method name// leaked its continuation!", as seemingly the runtime sees no guarantee that continuation.resume will ever be called.

What would be the right approach here?

Comment: How about using a custom ```Layout```?

Comment: @BenzyNeez Thanks, I have looked into custom Layouts. My problem is the following: the Shapes in the view actually constitute a graph. That is, they are linked by edges and the arrange algorithm takes the edges into consideration when placing the Shapes. In a Layout, I don't get the View itself, just get a LayoutSubview proxy which doesn't say more about itself than "I am a thing located at x,y and I am w,y large". If I could pass up some metadata here from the view, at least an ID, I could match these proxies up with the underlying graph data structure. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've just found LayoutValues in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layoutvaluekey . It seems like they would solve my problem, right?

Comment: I didn't know about ```LayoutValueKey```, so thanks for that lead. Yes, it looks like it might fit your needs well.

Comment: Okay, so the Shapes are now correctly arranged with my custom Layout. However, there is a problem. I would need to draw Edges between the Shapes. They are Paths and their start and end points depend on the Shape positions. I unfortunately cannot update the view from the Layout, I can only place my subviews at the calculated coordinates. So updating an ObservedObject bound to the Edge rendering algorithm in Layout.placeSubviews results in an error (as this may lead to recursive view updates).

Comment: Since it seems impossible to do any of the Edge coordinate calculation inside the AutoArrangingLayout that is placing the Shapes, I am back to my original question, as it would be much better to calculate all Shape and Edge positions beforehand, before even rendering the view. For that, all I would need to do is answer this question: "If I had a Shape view with the text X inside it, how wide and how tall would it be?". How can I do that? If I knew that before rendering anything, I could precalculate all Shape and Edge positions.

Comment: I have just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452647/how-we-can-get-and-read-size-of-a-text-with-geometryreader-in-swiftui , for finding out the width of a String with a given font without rendering it. However, I have word wrapping, so the height is also dynamic. I also have hyphenation, so the height is not simply textWidth/shapeMaxWidth*lineHeight. So once again the question boils down to measuring a complete View without rendering it on the screen.